# Embed Language only for specific sites in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7

How to embed the language/locale only for specific sites in Sitecore?

Let's say I have US site and URL for that will be http://exmaple.com

For the Canada site I have 2 languages, Hence the URL should be something like this.

http://exmaple.ca/en-ca

http://exmaple.ca/fr-ca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box to achieve this, since you can only set a single link provider and the settings apply across instances/usages of the solution.

I have previously blogged a solution which I used to implement [Site Specific Link Provider for Multisite Implementations in Sitecore](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/site-specific-link-provider-for-multi-site-implementation-in-sitecore/) which is essentially a switching link provider allowing you to define multiple Link Providers, each with different configuration for different sites.

This would allow you to create two link provider configurations:

```
<linkManager>
  <providers>
    <add name="provider-site1" languageEmbedding="never" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" ... />
    <add name="provider-site2" languageEmbedding="always" type="Sitecore.Custom.Links.SpecificLinkProvider, Sitecore.Custom" ... />    
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

And then in your sites definition specify which provider to use:

```
<sites>
  <site name="site1" linkProvider="provider-site1" ... />
  <site name="site2" linkProvider="provider-site2" ... />
  <site name="site3" ... />
</sites>
```

All the code code for this can be found in this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jammykam/daa151abeeac8a7029bf)

Alternatively, create your own Link Provider, inheriting from `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` and override the `GetItemUrl` method:

```
public override string GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions options)
{
    if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Name == "US-Site")
    {
        options.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Never;       
    }
    return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
}
```

And then patch this in to replace the default link provider:

```
<linkManager>
  <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">custom</patch:attribute>
  <providers>
    <add name="custom" type="MyProject.SiteLinkProvider, MyProject" languageEmbedding="always"  />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Comment: High quality answer, small addition tip beside the LanguageEmbedding you can also consider to toggle the useDisplayName for specific sites, to allow language specific urls see http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/change-linkmanager-config/

Comment: how to do this in sitecore 9.3?

Comment: @NewbieHere Swap out the LinkManager using DI https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/09/22/switching-link-manager/

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `languageEmbedding` setting is global for all sites. To make it site specific, you will need to create a custom `LinkProvider` inherited from the default one `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` and specify it in the configuration. Something like:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="custom">
<providers>
<clear/>   
<add name="custom" type="MyNamespace.LinkProvider, AssemblyName" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath"lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false"/>
</providers>
</linkManager>
```

Custom provider needs to override `languageEmbedding` option (to e.g. 'always' value) depending on the context site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this out of the box, but with a simple LinkProvider it should be possible. Example:

- you set the default url options to include the language
- in the LinkProvider you detect the current site
- if that current site is not your US site, get out by returning `base.GetItemUrl(item, options)`
- if that current site is your US site, you create new UrlOptions ('noLangOptions') based on the ones in your parameters but with `LanguageEmbedding.Never` and return `base.GetItemUrl(item, noLangOptions)`